# Determine the point on the curve $a ^ 2 x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 = a ^ 2$ in the first quadrant such that the area of ​the triangle by tangent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Problem:
Let the $a$ arbitrary . Determine the point on the curve $a ^ 2 x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 = a ^ 2$ in the first quadrant such that the area of ​​the triangle by tangent
the curve drawn at this point closes the axes is the lowest possible .

My work:
Let $y=kx+l$ be that tangent line in the first quadrant. 
We know that line goes through points $(0,l)$ and $(-\frac{l}{k},0).$ So area is $A=\frac{l*-\frac{l}{k}}{2}=-\frac{-l^2}{2k}$
But area depends of two variables and we want to depends on just one because we will than solving equation: $f'(l)$ or $f'(k)$.

Ok let's do this. First of all we will need $y'$ and we will find it by implicit differentiation.
$$a ^ 2 x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 = a ^ 2$$
$$2a^2x + 2yy'= 0$$
$$a^2x + yy'= 0$$
$$ yy'= -a^2x $$
$$ y'= \frac{-a^2x}{y} $$
So we know that $k=\frac{-a^2x}{y}$. By using equation of tangent line we can use write $l$ as variable of parametar $x$ and $y$.
$$y=kx+l$$
$$y-kx=l$$
$$y-\frac{-a^2x^2}{y}=l$$
$$\frac{y^2-a^2x^2}{y}=l$$
Ok  now we have again that our formula for area depends of two variables.
But let's use fact that $(x,y)$ is in the first quadrant.
$$a ^ 2 x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 = a ^ 2$$
$$y^2=a^2-a^2x$$
$$y=(a^2-a^2x)^{(\frac{-1}{2})}$$
We don't have negative solution because dot is in the first quadrant. 
Finally now we have want we want. Plugin in want we know in area formula and search solution for  $A'(x)=0$ Then we check second derivative to be sure it is our solution max or min. And we can easily chech what $a$ is.
Is this ok or maybe you have better idea?

Comment: First, you should have $(y^2\color{red}{+}a^2x^2)/y=l$. Second, you should have $y=(a^2-a^2x)^{\color{red}{+}1/2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parameterize this ellipse with $x=\cos\theta$ and $y=a\sin\theta$ and obtain the equation of the tangent at $\theta$ as $$ax\cos\theta+y\sin\theta=a$$

Then the area of the triangle is $$\frac 12\sec\theta \operatorname{cosec}\theta=\frac{a}{\sin 2\theta}$$ and this has minimum value $a$.
This occurs when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ thus giving the coordinates $(x,y)$